# Is there any way to give weight a negative value?

Tags: attributes, shipping-methods

Some of my items are collection only while some are not. I have set my collection only products to have a weight of 50. I have a shipping method setup so if an order has a weight of 50 or above, the collection method will be available.

The problem I have is that someone could theoretically add on a non collection product onto a collection order as the weight is above 50.

Is there anyway I could have negative weight so that a non collection item could be worth -99999 weight

This would eradicate the issue I am having.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach would be to update the logic of the shipping method itsself. Rather than use a negative or other fixed weight which could as you have seen already potentially have side effects use a seperate specific attribute on the product level "is_collection_only".

Then in your collectRates walk through each of the products and return false in the event that your product is found to be collection only.

This way you keep weight as a logical attribute (and and even use the correct value for the product in case in the future shipping becomes an option).

```
public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
{
    if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
        return false;
    }
    // Get Quote for basket 
    // Loop for each product 
    if ($product->getIsCollectionOnly()) {
        return false; 
    }
    // Remaining Logic for calculating price. 
}
```

You might want to add a system warning that product(s) are unavailable for delivery detailing the effected item.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 1, the validation for positive values only takes place in the backend form. To remove it, rewrite `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Helper_Form_Weight` and remove these parameters:

```
validate-zero-or-greater validate-number-range number-range-0-99999999.9999
```

If you update products using the web service, you also need to rewrite `Mage_Catalog_Model_Api2_Product_Validator_Product::_validateAttributes()`, and remove `weight` from this line:

```
$positiveNumberAttributes = array('weight', 'price', 'special_price', 'msrp');
```